# .Net 5 Api: Returning result to caller and later run some code

Tags: c#, .net, task, asp.net-apicontroller

Lets say I have a .NET 5 Controller that should return a result to a user:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getSomething")]
    public IActionResult FirstCall()
    {
        /** Process something as a reaction on what the user did **/
        var task = new Task(async () =>
        {
            /** Some work that takes longer but is not needed by user */
            await Task.Delay(10000);
        });
        task.Start();
        return Ok("The fast result for the user");
    }
```

But lets also say, that my software needs to do some internal work as a reaction of what the user did. This work is necessary, but is **not** producing any result that the user needs to see.
Is it legit to create a Task and cold start it with task.Start().
I want to do this, to improve the UX of the application. My user will get an **instant** result and does not have to wait for the operation.

Is this legit? Or a bad practice? Would it even work? Or is my task being aboarded once the controller action finishes?

**Update:**

The API I am calling is responding to a Single Page App. This is why I want to improve the speed.

Comment: by doing so you don't know if your Task ended correctly. Can't you use await and not block the FE, maybe using observable?

Comment: Of course I could just do an async operation. But then my user needs to wait longer... its juts about performance and UX.

Comment: Is a web application your FrontEnd?

Comment: Yes, it is an API responding to the operations of an SPA

Comment: why not using Promise or Observable... You don't block the UI part. so the user can do something else. but at the same time you can catch server-side errors if they happen. or intercepts the successful conclusion of the process.

Comment: No - the result is important for the user. The UX is totally fine with what is returned instantly. I just want the cleanup operation independend from returning the result to the user

Comment: Promises is perfect... but if you want you can read this documentation of [RXJS](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable)

Comment: Nothing on the client will execute something asynchronously on the server. You don't need RxJS to make asynchronous calls in Javascript. You can use `fetch(...).then(resp=>resp.....)` or `const resp=await fetch(...); await resp....;`

Comment: @Den the question is how to execute a background job on the server, not an async call on the client. Doing so is documented and there are duplicate questions already

Comment: Yes, Background Job on server. Where is it documented? Can you reference a duplicate question?

Comment: You're right.... But the question start from a wrong structure for me... In this api not need start a task async... You do this from not intercept the result from client...